# python file handling can't search all words

Tags: python, file-handling

Trying to search no of times word appears in a file using python file handling. For example was trying to search 'believer' in the lyrics of believer song that how many times believer comes. It appears 18 times but my program is giving 12. What are the conditions I am missing.

```
def no_words_function():
  f=open("believer.txt","r")
  data = f.read()
  cnt=0
  ws = input("Enter word to find: ")
  word = data.split()
  for w in word:
    if w in ws:
      cnt+=1
  f.close()
  print(ws,"found",cnt,"times in the file.")

no_words_function()
```

Comment: share us a sample data from believer.txt

Comment: Try `'word, word. word", word'.split()` in your Python interpreter.

Comment: https://replit.com/@ShivamMishra8/FileHandling-2#believer.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not considering camel case while searching, assuming the entered word in small case you can add below code:

```
  for w in word:
    if ws.lower() in w.lower():
      cnt+=1
```

Comment: It worked but there was no camelcase previously. They were all in small letters already.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you only find 12 of the 18 times "believer" occurs is because of your test inside the for loop.

Instead of writing

```
if w in ws:
  cnt+=1
```

you should reverse the order

```
if ws in w:
    cnt+=1
```

To understand why, let's look at one of the lines in you test: `You break me down, you build me up, believer, believer`. If you split this lines you get the following result:

```
line = "You break me down, you build me up, believer, believer"
line.split()
Out[26]: 
['You', 'break', 'me', 'down,',
 'you', 'build', 'me', 'up,',
 'believer,', 'believer']
```

As you can see, the ninth element in this list is `believer,`. If you test `'believer,' in 'believer'` the result will be `False`. However, if you test `'believer' in 'believer,'` the result will be `True`

As others have mentioned, it is also a good idea to convert the search string and your search word to lower case, if you want to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not cleaning the data of the trailing characters which can be `,`, `"`, '.' etc. This means your code will not find "believer," in the text

You are also not doing case comparisons. This means your code will not find "Believer" in the text. Based on your search needs you might want to do that.

For cleaning data:

```
word = data.split()
word = [w.strip("'\".,") for w in word] # Add other trailing characters you do not want
```

For case-insensitive search:

```
word = [w.lower() for w in word]
```